# Perl UMMF Tutorial?

Tags: perl, uml, diagram, xmi

I want to be able to create UML diagrams from source code - and I found [UMMF - UML Meta-Model Framework](http://search.cpan.org/dist/UMMF/). However, I could not find any tutorial to get me started on creating a diagram with two classes and a simple relationship between them.

Basically what I am trying to achieve for now, is to create a simple **two tables diagram** in a relation of 1..n:

[image: two tables diagram to realize with perl UMMF]

The XMI output for this diagram, is pretty verbose, because I created the diagram with Enterprise Architect - you can find this XMI file [here](http://pastebin.com/50daLe0a) (I could not embed the text here because is too big)

I want to use UMMF because it creates XMI files, based on perl object hierarchies that are related to [OMG UML](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/) standards and those files can be imported in any modelling tool that implement those standard.

So the question is, how can I create this diagram using **UMMF**? - it is not necessary to be that complex.

I need the diagram to have:

- two tables
- at least one table to have:

  - one field as **primary key**
  - one **indexed field**
  - one **regular** field (not indexed)
- a relation between the two tables

Also if you know of the existence of any good **Perl UMMF tutorials**, please show us their links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UML::Class::Simple can create XMI files from source code. That may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use UMMF to programmatically create UML models from Perl and export them to XMI.  However, UMMF only supports UML 1.5 --  a standard graphical diagram meta-model didn't exist until UML 2.0 AFAIK.

You might want to look at Graphvis: http://www.graphviz.org/

I've done some basic stuff to create UML-like diagrams with it.  It has some basic support for record-oriented diagrams.

Someone could probably write a XMI->Graphvis transformer using UMMF.  :)

BTW: I'm the author of UMMF.

Comment: Hi kurt, welcome to stackoverflow and thanks for your response - I was interested in being able to generate pure XMI files based on Perl code - the visualization would have been done by Enterprise Architect, Umbrello, or other software dedicated to UML modelling - unfortunately since then I got extremely busy and distracted by many other things and I couldn't study your framework anymore - I hope I'll got to have some time soon to start again

Comment: UMMF assumes knowledge of the UML metamodel, in fact all the Perl code is generated from a textual description of UML written in UML.  The key UML Element objects you need to connect are Model, Class, Association and Attribute.

http://ummf.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ummf/ummf/release/ummf-1.03/test/test2.pl?revision=1070&view=markup may be helpful.